# Center a button in a tiny div

Tags: html, css

I have a div with unknown height, though in this example I'm using 3px. I want to center the button but it seems to always offset by some arbitrary amount. I could do an absolute positioning trick dynamically once I know the height but I would prefer a css solution if possible.

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 3px;">      
  <div class="special">                               
    <input type="button" />                     
  </div>
</div>

div{                
  height: 100%; 
  overflow: visible;
}

.special{   
  position:relative;
  text-align: center;   
  padding: 1px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

input{  
  height: 100%; 
  width: 100px;
  min-height: 8px;
}
```

The idea is that with the min-height the button will overflow evenly over the top and bottom of the div.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N7zD7/)

Comment: Are you using a CSS reset? Google meyer reset if you aren't, you could be running into browser default CSS issues

Comment: @RickCalder I'm testing in chrome and IE and there is a little difference, but neither does what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this to work by doing the following:

CSS:

```
div {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: visible;
}
.special {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position:relative;
}
input {
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:-4px;
    margin-bottom:-4px;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    width:100px;
    min-height:7px;
}
```

Note the `input` declaration in particular. Instead of `height:100%` I used `position:absolute` with `top:0px` and `bottom:0px`. This will set the height to 100%. It needs to be position of absolute so that you can do `margin-top:-4px` and `margin-bottom:-4px` to get the overlap. You can see that it works for any height of the outer `<div/>`.

The JSFiddle below has some added controls so you can change the height of the .special `<div/>` without needing to refresh.

http://jsfiddle.net/bmyAW/8/

Comment: All this seems to do is negate the text-align positioning.

Comment: See this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bmyAW/1/. Is this what you are looking for? I also added `margin-top:-3px;`, and changed `min-height:8px` to `height:9px`, since it will need to be an odd number to overlap evenly with the 3px `<div/>`.

Comment: No, because if I change the div height it is no longer centered. I'm looking for a general solution that doesn't require knowing the dimensions ahead of time.

Comment: Centered horizontally or vertically?

Comment: Close, but the button only overlaps on the bottom, not the top, which you can see if you decrease the div height or change the button min to 9px.

Comment: Just decrease the `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` to `-4`. See the [updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmyAW/8/).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25449/discussion-between-aaron-blenkush-and-peter)